# Hi hope somebody can help me, trying to plot a graph of \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(20-x)}} and really struggling, thanks in advance

Tags: pgfplots

Hi hope somebody can help me, trying to plot  a graph of \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(20-x)}} and really struggling, thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[declare function={f(\x)=1/(pi*sqrt(\x*(20-\x)));}]
  \addplot[domain=1:19] {f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` produces such a plot.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To the down voter: there's no need; we get these questions *all of the time*. Let's help people make their questions better, not discourage them from the community. To the OP: please always include (if possible) a complete minimum working example that demonstrates what you've tried, and what's not working. It's best if you help any potential people that can help as much as possible :)

Comment: Hi thank you so so much! spent hours trying to do that haha